# unexpected error has been detected by Java Runtime Environment

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss

I am generating report(CSV) through java and i am using hibernate for fetching the data from data base.

Part of my code is as below :

```
ScrollableResults items = null;
String sql = " from " + topBO.getClass().getName() + " where " + spec;
StringBuffer sqlQuery = new StringBuffer(sql);
Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(sqlQuery.toString());
items = query.setFetchSize( 1000 ).setCacheable(false).scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);
list = new ArrayList<TopBO>();
// error occurs in while loop. at the time of fetching more data.
while(items.next())
{           
     TopBO topBO2 =(TopBO) items.get(0); 
     list.add(topBO2 );
     topBO2 = null;
}
sessionFactory.evict(topBO.getClass());
```

### Environment info

- **JVM config** : Xms512M -Xmx1024M -XX:MaxPermSize=512M -XX:MaxHeapSize=1024M
- **Jboss** : JBoss 5.1 Runtime Server
- **Oracle** : 10g
- **JDK** : jdk1.6.0_24(32-bit/x86)
- **Operating System** : Window 7(32-bit/x86)
- **Ram** : 4gb

**Error** : When i fetch the data up to 50k it works fine. but when i am fetching the data more then it. it gives me the error :

```
#
# An unexpected error has been detected by Java Runtime Environment:
#
# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: requested 4096000 bytes for GrET in C:\BUILD_AREA\jdk6_11\hotspot\src\share\vm\utilities\growableArray.cpp. Out of swap space?
#
#  Internal Error (allocation.inline.hpp:42), pid=1408, tid=6060
#  Error: GrET in C:\BUILD_AREA\jdk6_11\hotspot\src\share\vm\utilities\growableArray.cpp
#
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (11.0-b16 mixed mode windows-x86)
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# D:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\bin\hs_err_pid1408.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

When i set the `Xms512M -Xmx768M -XX:MaxPermSize=512M -XX:MaxHeapSize=768M` It throws me another exception :

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Comment: What operating system you use?

Comment: Increase your machine RAM/SWAP.

Comment: @SachinVerma How much i need to update? Is there any solution other then this ?

Comment: @KevalTrivedi OS and JVM is x86 or x64?

Comment: What is the memory usage in your windows task manager with culprit JVM running?

Comment: Currently it shows 901,452K

Comment: Your total system memory usage %age ?

Comment: How can i check system memory usage ?

Comment: @KevalTrivedi `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` shows that this time memory doesn't suffice to a Java-code. Try to run with `-server -Xms512M -Xmx1024M`

Comment: If i increase that memory with -Xms512M -Xmx1024M then it gives me An unexpected error has been detected by Java Runtime Environment:

Answer (score 0):

`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` generally caused due to lacking required Heap space. What you can do is to increase your jvm heap size using flag `-Xmx1548M` or more MB than 1548.

But you seems like running out of System memory so you should use a better JVM that handles memory more efficiently and I suggest a JVM upgrade. How about upgrading your JVM 1.6 to some more recent versions?

Comment: This error in internal JVM C-heap. Increasing of Java heap hardly will be able to help.

Comment: Whats your system configuration ?

Comment: How to increase the JVM C-heap ?

Comment: C heap is not JVM heap. JVM heap is a part of C heap.

Comment: Your first point doesn't work for me to increase the size of -Xmx flag

Comment: @KevalTrivedi increasing of JVM heap is a bad advice in this case. On the contrary it, most likely, should be reduced.

Answer (score 0):

The solution of this problem can be uncommon. Try to use recommendations from article [OutOfMemoryError: Out of swap space - Problem Patterns](http://javaeesupportpatterns.blogspot.ru/2012/03/outofmemoryerror-out-of-swap-space.html).

> There are multiple scenarios which can lead to a native
>   OutOfMemoryError.
>
> - Native Heap (C-Heap) depletion due to too many Java EE applications deployed on a single 32-bit JVM (combined with large Java
>     Heap e.g. 2 GB) * most common problem *
> - Native Heap (C-Heap) depletion due to a non-optimal Java Heap size e.g. Java Heap too large for the application(s) needs on a single
>     32-bit JVM
> - Native Heap (C-Heap) depletion due to too many created Java Threads e.g. allowing the Java EE container to create too many Threads
>     on a single 32-bit JVM
> - OS physical / virtual memory depletion preventing the HotSpot VM to allocate native memory to the C-Heap (32-bit or 64-bit VM)
> - OS physical / virtual memory depletion preventing the HotSpot VM to expand its Java Heap or PermGen space at runtime (32-bit or
>     64-bit VM)
> - C-Heap / native memory leak (third party monitoring agent / library, JVM bug etc.)

I would begin with such recommendation to troubleshooting:

> Review your JVM memory settings. For a 32-bit VM, a Java Heap of 2 GB+
>   can really start to add pressure point on the C-Heap; depending how
>   many applications you have deployed, Java Threads etc… In that case,
>   please determine if you can safely reduce your Java Heap by about 256
>   MB (as a starting point) and see if it helps improve your JVM memory
>   “balance”.

It is also possible to try (but it is more difficult in respect of labor costs) to upgrade your environment to 64-bit versions of OS and JVM, because 4Gb of physical RAM will be better utilized on x64 OS.

Comment: If i reduce the java heap memory it throws me outofmemory exception.

Comment: @KevalTrivedi the best way to find out, how many native or JVM memory needs - to profile your app. I advise attentively study article.